# How to display SQL query in different table by GROUP BY

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, foreach

Ok so my SQL query is:

```
$image_results = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM uploaded_images GROUP BY album_title') ;
```

What I now want to do is have a different set of results for each different *album_title* that outputs the album title in a  tag and then show a list of items that have that album title.

Here is what i have so far:

```
<?php foreach ($image_results as $result => $coll):?>
    <h4><?php echo $coll->album_title;?></h4>
    <?php foreach ( $coll->file_name as $i => $row ) : ?>
         <p><img src="http://example.com/<?php echo  $row->file_name; ?>"/></p>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Do you mean you wish to issue another SQL statement after outputing the `album_title`?

Comment: I know but i like to use them like that

Comment: I want to out put something like this:

Comment: ALBUM ONE
album 1 item
album 1 item
album 1 item
album 1 item


ALBUM 2
album 2 item
album 2 item
album 2 item
album 2 item
album 2 item

Comment: Do you have a table that holds the items, and what are the related fields?  You can probably use a `JOIN` statement with an `ORDER BY` instead of a `GROUP BY`.

Comment: ive updated my question to what i think i need it to do

Comment: Ah, okay.  I understand now.  I shall post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your question update, I think this is what you are looking for.  Note that I have used `ORDER BY` instead of `GROUP BY`.  Grouping is used when things like `SUM`, `AVG`, or other aggregate functions are used.  This can be handled all in one loop:

```
$image_results = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM uploaded_images ORDER BY album_title');
$curTitle = '';
foreach($image_results as $result => $col) {
    if($curTitle !== $col['album_title']) {
        $curTitle = $col['album_title'];
        echo "<h4>$curTitle</h4>";
    }
    echo '<p><img src="' . $col['file_name'] . '" /></p>';
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for that. I had to tweek it to suit wordpress but it worked great thanks

Comment: @MikeGarlick You're welcome.  Sorry you had to tweak it.  I am not too familiar with wordpress.  Glad it worked, though.

Comment: ahh no worries its only stupid stuff like '$col['album_title']' needs to be '$col->album_title'.

thanks again

Answer (score 0):

The easy way:

```
$album_titles = array();
$image_results = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM uploaded_images GROUP BY album_title') ; 
foreach ($image_results as $result){
   $album_titles[ $result['album_title'] ][] = $result;
}

foreach( $album_titles as $title -> $images ){
 echo "<h4>".$title."</h4>";
   foreach( $images as $image ){
      echo "<br/>".$image['file_name'];
   }
}
```

So you select it all, make an array of the titles and output everything with the same title.